# Mounted volume not shown in prometheus node export

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I have a cloud server with a mounted volume /dev/sdb on /mnt/HC_Volume_1111

```
# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 38.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1    8:1    0   38G  0 part /
├─sda14   8:14   0    1M  0 part 
└─sda15   8:15   0  122M  0 part /boot/efi
sdb       8:16   0  100G  0 disk /mnt/HC_Volume_1111
sr0      11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

I try to get the free space of this volume in my prometheus grafana dashboard, but I only receive the information for my /dev/sda.

This is my query in Grafana:

```
100 - (node_filesystem_avail_bytes{instance="testurl.com:9100", fstype="ext4"} / node_filesystem_size_bytes{instance="testurl.com:9100", fstype="ext4"} * 100)
```

How to get the information for my mounted volume as well?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 2):

I added the the following args to my prometheus-node-exporter service and now it's working

```
--collector.filesystem.ignored-mount-points=^/(dev|proc|sys|var/lib/docker/.+)($|/) --collector.filesystem.ignored-fs-types=^(tmpfs|autofs|binfmt_misc|cgroup|configfs|debugfs|devpts|devtmpfs|fusectl|hugetlbfs|mqueue|overlay|proc|procfs|pstore|rpc_pipefs|securityfs|sysfs|tracefs)$
```